# cypress error: " Cannot read property 'fs.existsSync' of undefined"

Tags: cypress

I recently picked up the cypress config & tests for our project after the original developer left. I'm haivng problems getting the existing tests to run:
The tests all throw this error when running from the command line:

```
TypeError: The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.
. > fs.existsSync is not a function
```

When I start up the GUI, it throws the same error, like so:

[image: GUI failure mode]

I found nothing in the issues nor on the web, except to see that `fs.existsSync` is deprecated.

When I checked the cypress.io's gitter site, they recommended that I trap errors with the following code which I added to my `support/index.js` file:

```
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
    // returning false here prevents Cypress from
    // failing the test
    return false
})
```

And now cypress crashes with the following before even starting the GUI:

[image: crash before displaying GUI]

This is a basic test:

[image: basic test case using defined commands]

Which use a series of defined commands like so:

[image: defined command sample]

The tests were running when originally created; I have upgraded to cypress 4.8.0 with no luck.

Has anyone seen anything like this? I'd sure like to get these tests running again.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing the error due to this: `import 'Cypress';`

[image]

You need not explicitly import `Cypress`.

I too can reproduce the same error when I added the 'import' statement.

[image]